# Range and ActiveCell.Offset Run-time error '1004'

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to determine the minimum and maximum values of a 5 cell range (C:G) for all non-blank rows in a worksheet and place the respective results in columns L and M.

I'm getting a Run-time error '1004' Application-defined or object-defined error.

```
Sub test()
    ActiveSheet.Range("A1").Select
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
    Do While ActiveCell.Value <> Empty
        ActiveCell.Offset(0, 11) = WorksheetFunction.Min(Range(ActiveCell.Offset(0, 2), ActiveCell.Offset(0, 6)))
        ActiveCell.Offset(0, 12) = WorksheetFunction.Max(Range(ActiveCell.Offset(0, 2), ActiveCell.Offset(0, 6)))
        ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
    Loop
    ActiveSheet.Range("A1").Select
End Sub
```

I'm pretty sure my problem is in the specification of the range but not sure what it is.

The first and last selects are just a convention I use.

The second select is to step past a header row.

The third select is to increment the row.

If there is a simpler way to do this, please let me know.

Comment: [How to avoid using Select/Active statements](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/excel-macro-avoiding-using-select)

Answer (score 1):

I can't reproduce the error you mention, your code seems to run as is.

That said there a many ways to improve this code

1. Avoid `Select` (as mentioned in comments)
2. The `Application` object offers `Min` and `Max` functions, no need to use `WorksheetFunction`s for these
3. Better approach to `range` references is a combination of `Offset` and `Resize`

Your code, refactored to used these techniques

```
Sub Demo()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim rw As Range

    ' Get a reference to the source data range
    Set ws = ActiveSheet
    With ws
        Set rng = .Cells(2, 1)
        ' Just in case there is only one data row
        If Not IsEmpty(rng.Offset(1, 0)) Then
            Set rng = .Range(rng, rng.End(xlDown))
        End If
    End With

    ' Loop the range
    For Each rw In rng.Rows
        rw.Offset(0, 11) = Application.Min(rw.Offset(0, 1).Resize(, 5))
        rw.Offset(0, 12) = Application.Max(rw.Offset(0, 1).Resize(, 5))
    Next
End Sub
```

That said, you can go further and use a `Variant Array` approach.  This runs much faster than looping a range (impact will vary depending on number of data rows)

```
Sub Demo2()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim dat As Variant
    Dim res As Variant
    Dim i As Long

    ' Get a reference to the source data range
    Set ws = ActiveSheet
    With ws
        Set rng = .Cells(2, 1)
        ' Just in case there is only one data row
        If Not IsEmpty(rng.Offset(1, 0)) Then
            Set rng = .Range(rng, rng.End(xlDown))
        End If
    End With

    ' Set up source and result arrays
    dat = rng.Offset(, 2).Resize(, 5).Value
    ReDim res(1 To UBound(dat, 1), 1 To 2)

    With Application
        ' Loop the array
        For i = 1 To UBound(dat, 1)
            res(i, 1) = .Min(.Index(dat, i))
            res(i, 2) = .Max(.Index(dat, i))
        Next
    End With

    ' Return results to sheet
    rng.Offset(0, 11).Resize(, 2) = res
End Sub
```

Another technique is to avoid a loop entirely by (temporarily) placing formula into the sheet in one go. This will be *much* faster still (for more than a few data rows)

```
Sub Demo3()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim rw As Range

    ' Get a reference to the source data range
    Set ws = ActiveSheet
    With ws
        Set rng = .Cells(2, 1)
        If Not IsEmpty(rng.Offset(1, 0)) Then
            Set rng = .Range(rng, rng.End(xlDown))
        End If
    End With

    ' Place formulas into sheet
    rng.Offset(0, 11).FormulaR1C1 = "=Min(RC[-9]:RC[-5])"
    rng.Offset(0, 12).FormulaR1C1 = "=Max(RC[-9]:RC[-5])"

    ' replace formulas with values (optional)
    rng.Value = rng.Value
End Sub
```

Comment: Chris,
Your suggestions worked well - than you for your help.

Comment: Chris, Your suggestions worked well - thank you for your help.
Your attention to detail (empty row check) makes me think you've been doing vba for some time. Can you suggest a good book for a beginner?

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
Sub MinAndMax()
    Dim rng As Range
    Set rng = Range("A2:A" & Range("A2").End(xlDown).Row)

    Range("L1") = WorksheetFunction.Min(rng)
    Range("M1") = WorksheetFunction.Max(rng)
End Sub
```

- Define the range upfront
- Write the `min` and `max` to the cells directly

Comment: Alex, thanks for your response. I erred in my initial question. I should have said "for EACH non-blank row" instead of " for ALL non-blank rows" -  I was looking to create min/max for each row.